# How can I run recursive function in cypress or find length with async await

Tags: javascript, recursion, cypress, e2e-testing

I am running tests using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/).

I have an array of *Litecoin* addresses. I am trying to set first in the input. Then submit the form.

If the address is duplicate then a notification is displayed and submit button will be not visible. The same I want to set for the second element and so on till end of the array.

I tried recursive function:

```
function runTillElementFound (totalCount, currentCount, litecoin_addresses)
    {
        var self = this;
        if (currentCount < totalCount) {
            return cy.get('body').then(($body) =>
            {
                if ($body.find(dash_page.save_wallet_circle_btn)) {
                    //if there is save button then set address and submit form
                    cy.log('taken address: ' + litecoin_addresses[ currentCount ]);
                    dashact.fill_wallet(litecoin_addresses[ currentCount ]);
                    cy.log('address is filled');
                    dashact.submit_wallet(true, 0);
                    self.runTillElementFound(totalCount, currentCount++);
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false; //if element not present after Max count reached.
        }
```

I try to call it:

```
it('Set wallet', () =>
    {
        cy.log('this is array length: ' + litecoin_addresses);
        runTillElementFound(20, 0, litecoin_addresses);
        /* comact.submit_form(true, 1);
        let ltc_address = promisify(dashact.get_wallet_value());
        cy.log('this is address: ' + ltc_address);
        //close popup and check that it is closed:
        popact.submit_payment(); */
    });
```

However I receive undefined:

[image: undefined error]

I have also tried non recursive function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < litecoin_addresses.length; i++) {
            cy.log('taken address: ' + litecoin_addresses[ i ])
            if (litecoin_addresses[ i ] == wallet_before_edit || litecoin_addresses[ i ].length == 0 || litecoin_addresses[ i ].startsWith('ltc')) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                cy.log('this is curent i: ' + i);
                dashact.fill_wallet(litecoin_addresses[ i ]);
                dashact.submit_wallet(true, null);
                cy.get('body').then(($body) =>
                {
                    // synchronously query from body
                    // to find which element was created
                    if ($body.find(com_page.not_message).length) {
                        // error was found, do something else here
                        cy.log('error was found');
                    }
                    else {
                        cy.log('error not found');
                        // input was not found, do something else here
                        i = litecoin_addresses.length;
                        cy.log('current i value: ' + i);
                    }
                })
            }
```

However it for sure, does not work, as i inside promise has one valued but in the loop it still remains the same.

Comment: Drop the `self.` -- accessing `this` from a function in [strict mode returns `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript), not `window`. Also it's unnecessary even if loose mode. Haven't checked the rest of the code, lemme know if you have further problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a specific array in your test code, you can easily get the length of the array by using the .lenght and access its elements by using the for loop.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain example code?